# In the value of gas constant $R$, what kind of mole is it?

Tags: thermodynamics, units, physical-chemistry, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant) gives $$R=8.3144598(48)\, \rm J\,mol^{−1}\,K^{−1}$$ But I want to ask how is it possible to write $\mathrm{mol}$ without a suffix? I mean, we must determine if we have $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of NaCl, or $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ HCl because from the definition of mole we must have a specific quantity (like $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ pencils, $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ balls, etc.).

Comment: What do you think the -1 stands for?

Comment: I've deleted some comments that were answering the question, and followups. Everyone please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements or requesting clarification, not for answering.

Answer (score 3):

As the linked page in Wikipedia from the question explains:

> The gas constant R occurs in the ideal gas law, as follows:
>
> PV=nRT . . .
>
> where P is the absolute pressure (SI unit pascals), V is the volume of
>   gas (SI unit cubic metres), **n is the amount of gas (SI unit moles)**
>   . . .  and T is the thermodynamic temperature (SI unit kelvins).

The moles of whatever gas molecule the formula is being applied to and corresponds to the units of "n" in  the formula.

The ideal gas law holds true without regard to the specific kind of molecular gas involved (within the ideal gas law's range of applicability), so it isn't necessary to specify.

Comment: Or even a mixture of different gases.  The ideal gas law can be applied to "air with the appropriate "molecular weight" .

Comment: @DJohnM Definitely.